# ReactJS - How to pass state data and functions from one functional component to other component?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-props

In react app, I am trying to use `react-redux` and `hooks` with the basic CRUD, search and sort operations for an array of objects.

My main component is functional component by using imports like

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducer';
const store = createStore(reducer);

function Friends(props) {
  const [friends, setFriends] = useState(store.getState().friends);
  ...
}
```

And I am to accessing a `store` inside a `Friends` component is like,

```
 function deleteFriend(id) {
   store.dispatch({type: 'DELETE_FRIEND', friendId: id});
   setFriends(store.getState().friends);
 }

 function onSortClick() {
   store.dispatch({ type: 'SORT_FRIENDS' });
   setFriends(store.getState().friends);
 }

<Route path="/list">
  <List result={friends} onSortClick={onSortClick} onDeleteClick={deleteFriend} />
</Route>
```

Now the issue is, while sorting an array I am getting an updated `friends` in the current component (`console.log(friends);`) but in `List` component I am not getting it as `props.result`.

Please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When component comes under routing then use `Redirect` option separately with required condition (eg: `{isChecked && <Ridirect ... /> }`).

```
<Redirect to="/list">
   <List result={friends} onSortClick={onSortClick} onDeleteClick={deleteFriend} />
</Redirect>
```

In this way, sorting will happen by re-rending the `<List>` component.

Though I am new to reactjs, I found this answer myself. Please let me know if any other solution/suggestions.